# Build a local mail-server

Tags: mail-server

I want to set an email local server on my system. I found an article for Windows in which the guy use **[hmailserver](http://peterkellner.net/2012/03/11/how-to-setup-your-own-pop3imap-email-server-for-local-development-testing/)**. In this article seems that you don't need of an external DNS server. Is there anything like hmailserver for Ubuntu?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

`sudo apt-get install mail-stack-delivery`.  Also see https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MailServer.

Comment: I need something more specific for a local use.

Comment: @DarkSkull, did you read the link?  You will have to be more specific.